# Crop selected image and send to upload in android

Tags: android, crop

i get the image :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_GALLERY_CODE);
```

onActivityResult :

```
case REQUEST_GALLERY_CODE:
  {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
      try {
        String type = getFileExtension(data.getData());
        Bitmap bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), data.getData());
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, options, baos);;
        byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
        SendUploadRequest(byteArray, type);
      } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    break;
  }
```

it's work fine and upload image to server.
i want when an image selected , user must select itself area of image and crop it to 400*400 the croped image send to server.
Thanks
more details:
[image]

Comment: Well you have already a bitmap `bmp'. Resize it before you compress it. Or what exactly do you consider what has to be done with cropping?

Comment: i want : user select's area of image that want to save as his profile.

Comment: Ok. Then do that before sending. It is unclear what your problem is.

Comment: post updated.more details in image.

Comment: That was not needed. That was clear. You should instead tell why you do not manage to let an image be cropped.